# Can the properties in a tomato help make hair curl?

Tags: organic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry

Is it possible for the active properties of a tomato to turn your hair from straight to curly? And what are the active ones that do this and why?

Comment: Do you mean by eating tomatoes?  Or putting them in your hair?  Or???

Comment: What are active properties?

Comment: I'm not really sure this is on-topic here. Unless you are interested in specific chemical processes then I will vote to close this as off-topic.

Comment: I would have guessed it to be the other way around, that the acidic components found in tomatoes would break the disulfide bonds in hair protein allowing the curls to "relax".

Comment: Tomatoes do contain interesting compounds! One of them, responsible for the red colour, is *lycopene*, a carotenoid. These compounds are known to be radical scavengers and antioxidants. It seems that mixtures of squashed tomatoes and olive oil are used for hair treatment, but that's not my league. However, I find it unlikely to achieve  the effect of a permanent here.

Comment: I suggest to leave the question open . Let's be a tad more relaxed with questions concerning [tag:everyday-chemistry] and sink more do-my-homework instead ;)

Comment: Nice question. Hair care is a multi-billion dollar industry globally, and one that is very much hinged around chemistry. Can't see how this question is not about chemistry.

Comment: From what I know, hair straightening/curling, both require the reduction of disulphide bridges using some form of reducing agent and then allowing them to reform once the hair has straightened/curled so that the fibres hold their shape. Now, I don't know what you are referring to when you say "active" properties of tomatoes, but if the fruit contains compounds which can do what I've described above, then yes it could be possible.